# 2 сайта на 1 Symfony

Tags: symfony2

Как на одном Symfony запустить 2 сайта? Чтобы были доступны классы, сервисы и т.д сразу для 2 сайтов.

Была идея создать 2 папки web (ну и переименовать соответственно), но маршрутизация всё равно одна. Так же была идея создать окружение, но файлы в web будут одни включая robots.txt

Подскажите как сделать.

Comment: ну я по домену смотрю что запрошено, потом принимаю решение какой контент отдавать.

Comment: Можно поподробнее, я так понимаю что в AppKernel.php надо написать, чтоб в зависимости от сайта подключались разные пакеты bundles? Но а как быть с окружением разработчика?

Comment: чтобы подробнее, тогда надо и постановку задачи подробнее :) некоторые наброски по мультисайтовости есть в цмс-ке http://smart-core.org/, которая пока немного в замороженном состоянии находится, то надеюсь скоро опыть продолжится разработка ;)

Comment: Ещё один вопрос. У меня версия 2,1,3 и при попытку ввести команду выдаёт ошибку "Parse error: syntax error", что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ошибка парсера означает что вы допустили ошибку в коде или файле настроек.